# heavy write to disk activity as soon as I turn on computer

Tags: security

Can someone tell me if something nefarious is going on?

I recently had to wipe my drive (losing all my data) and do a reinstall. So, I've been using the new 15.04 for 3 weeks without incident. 
But I believe what caused my old system to crash is happenning again.

There is alot of heavy writing onto disk activity even though I've not opened any programs and I've just turned on the computer and all the while I can't access the internet.

I've decided to keep the computer of lest whatever program in there that is writing onto my drive succeeds in it's purpose.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You have no idea why this happened twice ? Not even a little one ? Have you checked the system monitor while this is happening ?

Comment: It's from observing my system monitor that I realize that there is writing activity on my hard drive. I don't have any idea what happened the first time.  Also, my computer briefly shows a different time zone when I turn on the computer before reverting back to my local time zone.

Answer (score 0):

"Just turning off" your computer can leave your disk in an inconsistent state, so that the next boot has to do a bunch of disk I/O to recover the disk. If you "just turn it off" during this process, the disk state gets worse. Repeat enough times, and your system will fail.

Suggestion:

Reboot your computer. Note the (computer) time

Hit "/" or "F12" (I cannot recall which, offhand, try each) to see boot messages.

Watch the messages.

Allow the disk activity to complete.

Look at the log entries in `/var/log/{kern.log,syslog,boot,boot.log,bootstrap.log,dmesg}` with time/date fields after the time of reboot noted above. I am old-school and use `less`, you could use `Applications->Utilities->System Log`, or any other tool of your choice.

In addition, you could investigate these packages, available through `sudo apt-get install` or `synaptic` or the `Software Center`

```
bootchart - boot sequence auditing  
pybootchartgui - boot sequence visualisation  
bootlogd - daemon to log boot messages
```

Comment: I changed my password, updated, and ran CLAMTK. Everything seems to be okay now. I don't know if what I did fixed the problem. But at present the writing activity appears to have stopped, I can get on the internet again. System seems stable. Sorry, I have no tech background to explain why...my pseudonym techQR stands for techquestions...thanks, waltinator. if I start seeing those problems again, I'll try your solution.